# delete functionality wordpress

Tags: php

```
if($author_id == '1' || $role !== 'employer'){
    //echo "hi"; exit;
    $titles_to_remove = array_diff($currenttitles, $Rstitle);
    //echo '<pre>'; print_r($titles_to_remove); exit;
    foreach ($titles_to_remove as $post_id => $post_title) {
        wp_delete_post( $post_title, true );
    }
}
```

Comment: can any one please help me i wrote above code for delete posts for particular author and role

Comment: but that is not working it will delete all posts

Comment: Where are you getting the initial variables - i.e. `$currenttitles`, `$author_id`, and `$role`?

Comment: Can you post the full code? Without knowing where those variables come from and what they're meant to contain/how they're processed, it's impossible to debug this

Comment: Please edit your post to include more detail on (1) what you are currently doing and (2) what is not working.  Include all relevant code.  The more detail in your question, the more likely it will be that you are able to get some help.